# Can Compiz work in an Ubuntu guest in VMware workstation 9?

Tags: compiz, vmware, opengl

OpenGL it's supported in VMware Workstation 9

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws90/doc/workstation-90-release-notes.html#OpenGL

So Compiz theoretically can run inside a Ubuntu guest in VMware Workstation 9, It's possible or not?

I saw that Virtual Box Linux guest can run Compiz, VMware can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Compiz can run on a guest in VMWare Workstation 9. Compiz has worked on the standard X.Org server since May 22, 2006 by using Accelerated Indirect GLX ([AIGLX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIGLX))

Edit: Compiz depends on OpenGL rendering which is what previously prevented it from being compatible with VMWare Workstation.  The current version of VMWare WS supports proper OpenGL rendering and because of this it should be able to run Compiz once you have the proper drivers installed on the guest machine.

Comment: Thanks @Danny I am checking AIGLX, do you have more info or workarounds in VMware to get Compiz working?

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement AIGLX yourself, X.Org does that for you. Simply installing as you normally would should work.

Comment: Well! It work but with bugs, Compiz crashes a lot when I tried to move the 3D Cube, I'll check with a clean install of kubuntu

Comment: Thanks @Danny, I did the first test in a virtual machine upgraded from WS 8 to 9 with some use and probably there is still something wrong, in a clean install of WS 9 work perfectly :)